# Localization of cordova APP is not working

Tags: android, cordova, localization

APP is in pause state. I am changing the language(localization) of the phone afterwards when I select the app from recent history(pause state to resume state). The following lifecycle methods are calling in following order 
onDestroy
onCreate
onStart
onResume
onPause
onStop
onDestroy 
but APP is not opening(view is not appearing).
Here I have given the source code of activity and android manifest file. 
Any help is appreciated?

```
public class CordovaExample extends DroidGap  {
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
          Log.i("onCreate Called","onCreate Called");
     }
     @Override
     protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
        Log.i("OnStart Called","OnStart Called");
    }   
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        Log.i("onResume Called","onResume Called");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        Log.i("onPause Called","onPause Called "+Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
        Log.i("onStop Called","onStop Called");

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i("onDestroy Called","onDestroy Called");

    }
}
```

manifestfile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.apache.cordova.rest"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />

    <application
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
            android:name="org.apache.cordova.rest.CordovaRestClient"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the following Java File in cordova library project

framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebView.java

Replace the following line of code

```
if (url.startsWith("file://") || url.startsWith("javascript:") || Config.isUrlWhiteListed(url))
```

to

```
 if (url.startsWith("file://") || url.startsWith("javascript:") || Config.isUrlWhiteListed(url)&& !url.equals("about:blank"))
```

It is working fine now